# Precise Definition of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \sigma(A)]$ Conditional Expectation of Random Variable given Sigma Algebra generated by a set

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, measure-theory

I want to define **precisely**, **exhaustively** and **constructively** the conditional expectation of a random variable given the sigma algebra generated by a set. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230545/intuition-for-conditional-expectation-of-sigma-algebra) question has some discussion on it but the definition is not made explicit.

#### Set Up

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space (Banach space should be enough) and $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ be a random variable whose expectation exists and $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$. Let $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{F}$ be an event and define the sigma algebra generated by it as
$$
\sigma(\mathsf{A}) := \{\emptyset, \Omega, \mathsf{A}, \mathsf{A}^c\}.
$$
The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \sigma(\mathsf{A})]:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ is a $\sigma(\mathsf{A})$-measurable random variable such that
$$
\int_\mathsf{B} X(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \int_\mathsf{B}\mathbb{E}[X\mid \sigma(A)](\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega) \qquad\qquad\forall\, \mathsf{B}\in\{\emptyset, \Omega, \mathsf{A}, \mathsf{A}^c\}. \qquad\qquad (*)
$$
I would like to **construct** this random variable. For instance, when $\mathsf{A} = \Omega$ and $\sigma(\mathsf{A}) = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ then it's easy to show that the constant random variable $Y(\omega) = \mathbb{E}[X]$ does the job. When $\mathsf{A}\neq \Omega$ things get a bit more complicated. We aim means that to find a version of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \sigma(\mathsf{A})]$, that is a random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ that is $\sigma(\mathsf{A})$-measurable and satisfies $(*)$. I cannot show that either holds (constructively). Even simply showing measurability is tricky because I don't know how to construct this random variable.

###### Measurability

Most measure theory books define the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathsf{A}]$ to be a number, typically
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathsf{A}] = \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A})}\int_\mathsf{A} X(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega) & \text{ if } \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}) > 0 \\
    \text{any value in } \mathsf{E} & \text{ if } \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
My guess is that this number must appear somewhere in our definition of the random variable $Y(\omega) = \mathbb{E}[X\mid \sigma(\mathsf{A})](\omega)$. Recall that for $Y(\omega)$ to be $\sigma(\mathsf{A})$-measurable we require that for any $\mathsf{C}\in\mathcal{E}$
$$
Y^{-1}(\mathsf{C}) \in \{\emptyset, \Omega, \mathsf{A}, \mathsf{A}^c\}.
$$
Now when $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}) > 0$ then one has that $Y^{-1}(\mathsf{C})\in\sigma(\mathsf{A})$ because
$$
Y^{-1}(\mathsf{C}) = \{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, \mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathsf{A}]\in\mathsf{C}\} = \begin{cases}
    \emptyset & \text{if } \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A})^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X 1_\mathsf{A}]\in\mathsf{C}\\
    \Omega & \text{if } \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A})^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X 1_\mathsf{A}]\notin\mathsf{C}.
\end{cases}
$$
When $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}) = 0$ things get more tricky. Ideally I would want that for any $\mathsf{C}\in\mathcal{E}$ we have that $Y^{-1}(\mathsf{C})$ is either $\mathsf{A}$ or $\mathsf{A}^c$. I cannot seem to find a way of defining $Y$ so that this is true.

Comment: For definitions see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/450381/919. For examples of constructing a conditional expectation see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74339/919.  For much more about this subject please search our site for the keywords: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sigma+algebra+conditional+expectation.  A quick inspection of those hits suggests everything you ask here has answers already.

Comment: @whuber They define $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]$ for a general sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$, but the point of my question is when that sigma algebra is the smallest sigma algebra containing a set $\mathsf{A}\subset\Omega$. I understand the general definition of conditional expectation!

Comment: That's a basic mathematical concept: that's what it means for one mathematical structure to *generate* another.  Neither I nor, I suspect, most visitors to this page want to wade through the entire post to ferret out what you're trying to ask.  Could you be short, explicit, and clear?

Comment: @whuber My question is simple: how do you construct the random variable $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \sigma(\mathsf{A})]$? I know it's just a special case of a more general definition, but I want to construct it

Comment: @whuber You say that everything I ask has been answered already. I don't think it has. I am linking in my question to another post, but no where that I could find **constructs** the random variable

Comment: That's why I provided the second link in my first comment: that post presents an explicit construction of such a random variable.  Your comment tells me you haven't actually visited these links to look for answers.

Comment: @whuber Okay I am starting to understand, thank you for the reference. I am confused about your comment *"Because neither of these events can be decomposed (nontrivially) into smaller ones, the conditional expectation must have a constant value on each one"*. How do you show this matematically?

Comment: These are called "atoms."  They are part of the sigma algebra itself.  That statement is about a particular sigma algebra.  It's merely an (easily) verifiable fact about it.

Comment: @whuber Sorry I am still confused. Does it mean that in general for a sigma algebra such as $\sigma(\mathsf{A}) = \{\emptyset, \mathsf{A}, \mathsf{A}^c, \Omega\}$ any $\sigma(\mathsf{A})$-measurable function $X$ is constant on these sets? That is $X(\omega)=\text{constant}$ on $\omega\in\mathsf{A}$ and $X(\omega)=\text{constant}$ for $\omega\in\mathsf{A}^c$? But then if this is the case $X$ cannot be constant on $\Omega$..

Comment: When $A$ is an atom, yes: the very definition of measurability (easily) implies any random variable must be constant on $A.$ That does not imply $X$ is a constant function on $\Omega$!