# How to compute a conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra that is not generated by a partition?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

This question is not asking for a general algorithm. Instead, a very specific, preferably simple, example would suffice. Similar questions have been asked and answered for sigma-algebras that are partition-generated. E.g., [How to compute conditional expectations with respect to a sigma field?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74332/how-to-compute-conditional-expectations-with-respect-to-a-sigma-field).

An acceptable answer would also require you to prove that

i. The sigma-algebra is not partition-generated.

ii. It is indeed a conditional expectation in the standard sense.

Comment: Could you explain what a "non partition-generated sigma algebra" is?

Comment: Of course. I presume you are familiar with the notion of a partition (a collection of non-intersecting subsets whose union equals the sample space $\Omega$) and a sigma-algebra generated by a collection of subsets (the smallest sigma-algebra contains that collection). So a sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ of the sample space $\Omega$ is non-partition-generated if there does not (exist a partition $\mathcal P$ of $\Omega$ such that $\mathcal F$ is the generated sigma-algebra of $\mathcal P$).

Comment: Thank you.  That sounds like it would be isomorphic to a *discrete* sigma algebra (namely, the power set of the partition)--and therein lies a key to the solution.