# What does "version" mean here?

Tags: probability, random-variable

In a paper I read about the following statement:

"Assumption 1. There is a version of $f(x)$ that is twice continuously differentiable"

Note that $f(x)=E(Y|x)$ is an unknown function to be estimated with kernel regression using data $\{Y_{i},X_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$.

My question is what does "a version" of a function being continuous mean? How does this assumption differ from the following statement:

"$f(x)$ is twice continuously differentiable"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$E(Y\mid x)$ is a conditional expectation, which [means it is a random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74332/how-to-compute-conditional-expectations-with-respect-to-a-sigma-field/74339#74339).

The distributional properties of random variables are not changed when changes are made to those variables that obviously do not change any probabilities associated with them.  In particular, **when $X$ and $X^\prime$ are random variables defined on the same probability space $\Omega$ and the chance that they differ is zero, we say each is a "version" of the other.**

It is also said that two versions of a random variable are [almost surely equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely).

Formally, $X^\prime$ is a version of $X$ when there is an event $\mathcal{E}\subset\Omega$ for which

1. $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal E) = 0$ ($\mathcal E$ is a set of measure zero) and
2. $X\mid_{\Omega\setminus\mathcal E} = X^\prime\mid_{\Omega\setminus\mathcal E}$ ($X$ and $X^\prime$ are the same function on the complement of $\mathcal E$).

It is an immediate (and obvious) consequence of probability axioms and definitions that $X$ and $X^\prime$ have the same distribution function and that $\mathbb{P}(X\ne X^\prime)=0.$

---

**For instance,** let $X$ be a random variable with a standard Normal distribution.  Define $X^\prime = X$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$ *except* for which $X(\omega)=0,$ where we may define $X^\prime = 1$ (say).  Because a Normal distribution has zero chance of equalling any particular value like $0,$ this does not change any of the distributional properties of $X:$ $X^\prime$ still has a standard Normal distribution.

---

**The same concepts hold in any measure space.**  It is possible, depending on the context, that the $f$ in the question is being considered as a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}.$ In such cases the sense of "version" means with respect to Lebesgue measure rather than a probability measure.  The usual terminology is that two "versions" of a function are equal [almost everywhere.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)  Thus, the assertion in the question could mean there exists a function $g$ and a set $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathbb{R}$ of Lebesgue measure zero for which property $(2)$ above holds: that is, apart from their values on $\mathcal E,$ $f$ and $g$ are the same function.

**Why is this important and interesting?**  Because, for instance, the function $g$ defined by

$$g(x) = x^2$$

is everywhere smooth, but the function $f$ defined to equal $g$ on the irrational numbers and otherwise is (say) equal to $-1$ on all rational numbers has no derivative anywhere.  Nevertheless, because the rational numbers have Lebesgue measure zero, $g$ is a version of $f.$  In this way we have stripped away "trivial" aspects of $f$ to focus on its basic underlying "structure" as revealed by $g.$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful, and is the clearest explanation I can imagine.